# Volver a una pestaña desde una nueva ventana

Tags: java, selenium, java-8, junit-5

estoy intentado automatizando una pagina web y me está dando problemas al regresar a la pestaña anterior de una nueva ventana para volver a simular o ejecutar otra consulta. Actualmente estoy usando en JUnit.
Este es mi metodo:

> //**scrollNoticias** localizo -> By **titleNoticias** =
> By.xpath("//div/p[contains(text(),'noticias')]");
> //scrollUntilElementIsVisible es un metodo para bajar el scroll de la pagina
> //. localizo **plus** By **plusNoticias** = By.xpath("//div/a[contains(text(),'+')]");
> goBack es un metodo que dice -> drive.navigete.back();
> ******El problema es que me devuelve hacía la pestaña de la pagina anterior y me da un error**.**Me encuentra el "+" que es un enlace pero al volver la página no encuentra el elemento**

---

```
    public void checkUltimaNoticias() throws IOException {

            WebElement scrollNoticias = findElementByLocator(titleNoticias);
            scrollUntilElementIsVisible(scrollNoticias, 3);
            String titulo = findElementByLocator(titleNoticias).getText();
            assertTrue(titulo, true);
            List<WebElement> plus = findElementsByLocator(plusNoticias);
            int i = 0;
            for (WebElement webElement : plus) {
                
                switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    
                    clickElement(webElement);
                    waitForWebElementByLocator(afterPlusNoticias);
                    waitSeconds(3);
                    goBack();
                    
                    break;
                case 1:
                    
                    clickElement(webElement);
                    waitSeconds(3);
                    goBack();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    clickElement(webElement);
                    waitSeconds(3);
                    goBack();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
              i ++;
       }
}
```

Este es el error: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.61)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#stale_element_reference
Build info: version: '4.1.2', revision: '9a5a329c5a'
System info: host: 'MacBook-Pro-de-Administrator.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:10ed:96d0:9bd6:9fa9%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '12.3', java.version: '18.0.1.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [53d932924a101ef0bfde8884063b3d81, clickElement {id=1f3deff6-03cb-4fc7-9035-f1e17ef07012}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 102.0.5005.61, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 101.0.4951.41 (93c720db8323..., userDataDir: /var/folders/km/c67r2yl101j...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:62515}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:62515/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 102.0.5005.61, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Element: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (53d932924a101ef0bfde8884063b3d81)] -> xpath: //div/a[contains(text(),'+')]]

Answer (score 0):

Hola te dejo el siguiente metodo

```
 public static void cambiarVentana(int pantalla) {
        try {
            ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
           driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(pantalla));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
        }
    }
```

Parametro:

- 0: Pantalla inicial
- 1: Pestaña nueva

Saludos.